# Spring Boot with Morphia Configuration: BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, morphia

Me and my project team created a Application with Morphia. Now we want to build a Webservice with Spring which uses the same Entity-Classes and Wrappers. But it seems like Spring tries to instatiate a Bean from the morphia library.

My pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
        <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

my Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The following Error gets thrown at startup

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: clusterListener can not be null
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... lines omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: clusterListener can not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
... lines omitted
```

The Error gets thrown at startup as soon as I add the morphia dependencies.

How do I have to configure Spring Boot to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Spring tries to Autoconfigurate the MongoDb driver. I managed to disable Autoconfiguration with following Configuration Annotation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MainApplication {}
```